What is the French term/name for Canonical Ubuntu?
I want to know the exact french name of the Canonical Ubuntu distribution. Is there a way to know how every version is named in French?  (French canadian market) - Could it be "Ubuntu de Canonical"?

Ubuntu isn't an english word; its South African. Canonical is a company which is heavily involved and sponsors Ubuntu, but is also involved in other markets. You can view French Ubuntu sites (eg. https://www.ubuntu-fr.org/) or view Canonical sites (they're the same sites being global), but Ubuntu is Ubuntu in all countries, and Canonical is just Canonical (https://canonical.com/)

@guiverc that looks like a good answer.

Ubuntu isn't an english word; its South African.
Canonical is a company which is heavily involved and sponsors Ubuntu, but is also involved in other markets.
You can view French Ubuntu sites (eg. https://www.ubuntu-fr.org/) or view Canonical sites (they're the same sites being global), but Ubuntu is Ubuntu in all countries, and Canonical is just Canonical (https://canonical.com/)

If interested in some history; https://ubuntu.com/20years maybe worth a view (as a starting point anyway) ...  Canonical Ubuntu is usually used on Canonical official releases (helping market their company/corporation); it'll be Ubuntu when it's community related.
